# How can I Bold First two words bold in a paragraph Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How can I Bold First two words bold in a paragraph Dynamically?

I am trying to bold first two words in the Paragraph what can i do ? for that

Using HTML Javascript Css Jquery AngularJs

Comment: Wrap them in some inline element like `span` and style them with CSS.

Comment: Thank for ur Response. But I want it as dynamically , Here i am not entering the text

Comment: Yes try to attempt this yourself as Paulie_D said. To get you started my approach might be to get the `<p>` tag, split the string into an array, prepend `<strong>`, append `</strong>` to mySplitArray[0] and mySplitArray[1], join the array with a `" "` to make it back into a string and replace the `<p>` tag with that. Split docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split and join docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="boldTwoWord">How can I Bold First two words bold in a paragraph Dynamically?</p>
    <br/>
    <p class="boldTwoWord">I am trying to bold first two words in the Paragraph what can i do ? for that</p>    
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elms = $(".boldTwoWord");
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        str = elms[i].innerText;
        var ret = str.split(" ");
        var str1 = ret[0];
        var str2 = ret[1];

        s1 = str.replace(str1, '<strong>$&</strong>');
        s2 = s1.replace(str2, '<strong>$&</strong>');
        elms[i].innerHTML = s2;
    }
</script>
</html>
```